# PHP errors for (isset) variables and optimization

Tags: php

My error logs get huge quick because I reference a ton of variables with may or may not exist. I have been going back through and starting to clean them up but wanted to see if there was a more effective (and cleaner) way of checking for php variables.

Currently I use as the following:

Example 1:

```
<?php
     if (isset($_SESSION['checked']) && $_SESSION['checked'] == "Y") {
        do something;
     }
?>
```

Example 2:
(within html form)

```
<input type="text" name="sample_number" onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['sample_number']; ?>" />
```

where sample number is displayed if it is set.

is there a better way to handle scenarios like these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little more verbose, but `array_key_exists()` is faster than `isset()` for checking array key presence, and `isset()` comes with the caveat that it will return false for `NULL` values (you may have intentionally set a variable to `NULL`, but `isset()` will be semantically wrong in that case).

So, in your first example:

```
<?php
    if(array_key_exists('checked', $_SESSION) && $_SESSION['checked'] == 'Y') {
        do something;
    }
?>
```

In your second example, I suggest using `array_key_exists()` and the ternary operator:

```
<input type="text" name="sample_number" onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?= array_key_exists('sample_number', $fields) ? $fields['sample_number'] : '' ?>" />
```

as it makes for a more compact solution without repeating your HTML through `if()` conditions.

Edit: I always like to initialize my variables at the earliest possible point, FWIW.  This can get tricky as there's always the potential overhead if, say, you had a slew of arrays you initialized but then didn't end up using them (eg, if they were only used in certain conditions), but then again everything's relative to your application.  There's no substitute for good judgment.

Comment: I never set my session varibles to NULL on my sites so the first part doesn't bother me so much.

Comment: I'll give the 2nd piece a shot though - seems interesting and I've never seen it before

Comment: Just for a quick reference: the ternary operator (`?:`) is in the format: `condition ? true_statement : false_statement`.  You'd want to use it like you would any other expression - not as a means to execute two functions conditionally, for example (you'd still want to use `if()` in that case).

Answer (score 2):

I usually write myself some function that gets me the values out of the related array (being it session, get or post). I usually make these function assign a default value, as I don't really care if a value is set or the default value is set (which leads to no special behaviour).

Essentially, a function could look like this:

```
function getSessionVar ( $name, $default = '' )
{
    if ( !isset( $_SESSION[$name] )
        return $default;

    switch ( gettype( $default ) )
    {
        'integer':
            return intval( $_SESSION[$name] );
            break;

        'double':
            return floatval( $_SESSION[$name] );
            break;

        default:
            return $_SESSION[$name];
     }
}
```

Then I just use this function at the beginning of a file/code block to get all variables I'm interested in and just work with the value of that variable.

Comment: `gettype()` is bad times, but using a datastore-like function is always an option.

Comment: a function operator is not really a solution for me, especially given the second example in my initial question. Although I do agree it is a good solution, probably not for the issue I'm facing, especially since variable values change often.

Answer (score 2):

isset is the method that they teach in Zend certification training.  You could take shortcuts and do the @ in front of the statement that's barking, or you could just turn the error level down, but I'm a firm believer that errors exist for a reason....well, most of them anyways.  Take your time and do it right.

Comment: good advice. Can you explain how the @ shortcut works? I can't find language online for it.

Comment: It's the error control operator (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php), but you really shouldn't use it unless you're absolutely sure that the result won't cause unexpected behavior within your application.

Comment: @mway, agreed, I'm not a big fan.  But for these simple declaration notices, it is one possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the best way around it, but if you badly need to report all errors but still wanna ignore the case you described up there, I guess you could do:

```
if ($test = @$_SESSION['checked'] && $test == 'Y') {
   do something
}
```